# how replace a value of cookie in cookie string using regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a cookie string like this 
`'user=sravan;XSRF-TOKEN=1212143;session=random'`
i need to check for the XSRD-TOKEN in the cookie string, if we have the `XSRF-TOKEN` in the  string then need to replace the value with 'test'

expected new string is `'user=sravan;XSRF-TOKEN=test;session=random'`

i tried this `(?<=XSRF-TOKEN).*$` but it is selecting the entire string after `XSRF-TOKEN=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `(?<=XSRF-TOKEN=)([^;]+)`, example:

```js
const str = 'user=sravan;XSRF-TOKEN=1212143;session=random';
const processed = str.replace(/(?<=XSRF-TOKEN=)([^;]+)/, "test");
console.log(processed);
```

But a better solution will be to parse the cookies and recreate the string.

Comment: to parse the cookies we need to do lot of work it seems , and why regex is not a preferred way ?

Answer (score 0):

This should only only select up until ;

```
(?<=XSRF-TOKEN)[^;]+
```

Or if you only like to select whats after = to ;

```
(?<=XSRF-TOKEN=)[^;]+
```

'user=sravan;XSRF-TOKEN=`1212143`;session=random'